# Replace frames with div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some pages with frameset and frame based layouts. Now I want to change those pages to div base layout.Need suggestions about how to go about it ? Is it possible to target a particular div like in frames? Let me know if there are any tutorials available for the same.

Comment: If you are using mvc you can map your frames to partial views easily

Comment: This is a very vague question, you haven't shown any of your own efforts, and your question doesn't really even make sense, since divs are not a replacement for frames. Please clarify what you mean to be a specific question, or go read any of the 5 billion blog articles about learning HTML in general.

Comment: Please clarify the question.  Are you asking how to layout divs in a particular layout?  If so, what is that layout?

Answer (score 2):

`<div>`s can't take their contents directly from a url like `<frame>`s do. You have three options.

1. manually enter the contents inside the `<div>`

   `<div>contents...</div>`
2. use a server-side language like php to get the contents from the url and print it inside the div

   `<div><?php echo file_get_contents( 'contents.html' ); ?></div>`
3. use Javascript/AJAX to make a request and get contents from 'contents.html' and write it in the `<div>`.

also note that `div` contents should not contain the `<html>` and `<body>` tags, only the contents of `<body>`.